# How to set "default" username to be used in ssh alias?

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to set an alias that would by "default" use a different username then my current one. Like so:

```
$ echo $USER          # outputs kamil
$ alias myssh='ssh -o User=somebody'   # non-working example of what I want to do
$ myssh server        # Uses somebody@server - all fine!
$ myssh root@server   # I want it to use root@server, but it does not. It connects to `somebody@server`!

# Easy testing:
$ myssh -v root@localhost |& grep -i 'Authenticating to'
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'somebody'
#                                          ^^^^^^^^ - I want root!
```

The code above does not work - the user in `root@server` is *overwritten* by `-o User=somebody`. I could do something along:

```
myssh() {
   # parse all ssh arguments -o -F etc.
   if [[ ! "$server_to_connect_to" =~ @ ]]; then    # if the use is not specified
        # use a default username if not given
        server_to_connect_to="somebody@$server_to_connect_to"
   fi
   ssh "${opts[@]}" "$server_to_connect_to" "${rest_of_opts[@]}"
}
```

but the requires parsing all ssh arguments in the function to extract server name and then add username to it. The solution would be to modify `~/.ssh/config` and add `Host * User somebody` - however I am on a machine with *no write access to home directory* (and no home directory at all, actually) and I can't modify the config file and I do not want to overwrite normal `ssh` operation anyway.

Is there a simple solution to specify "default overridable" user to connect to server without modifying `~/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 8):

Don't use an alias, just configure your ssh client. Edit (or create, if it doesn't exist) `~/.ssh/config` and add these lines:

```
Host rootServer
HostName server_to_connect_to
User root

Host userServer
HostName server_to_connect_to
User somebody
```

Save the file, and you can now run `ssh rootServer` to connect as `root` and `ssh userServer` to connect as `somebody`.

Comment: see https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/#shared-ssh-config-file-example
for more details. In my case it was enough to put this into ~/.ssh/config those 2 lines.
"Host my_servers_*"
"    user my_user_name"

Comment: Better yet, just make one entry for that host, and set the default username there. Then you can override with an arbitrary username from the commandline with `ssh override@server`. That is, I think, more in line with what the OP is asking.

Comment: @marcelm but that's just the normal, default behavior. The idea is to avoid needing to write out the username, otherwise there's no need for anything special at all.

Comment: OP's default username is `kamil`, but for some host they want to default to `somebody`, and sometimes override to `root`. My suggestion is to only use configuration to make `somebody` the default for that host, and use `root@thathost` to override.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could set the username using a variable, and fall back to the default:

```
myssh() {
  ssh -o "User=${user:-somebody}" "$@"
}
```

And use it like so:

```
myssh server  # use default user
user=root myssh -v server  # use root as the username
```

Comment: tip of the day: instead of `ssh -o User=me`, you can use `ssh -l me`.

Answer (score 0):

I can generate a temporary file and pass that file to `ssh` as configuration with `-F` with the `Host * User somebody` added to it.

```
myssh() {
    (
        # in a subshell, so that `trap` will not affect parent
        local tmp
        tmp=$(mktemp --tmpdir .cis-ssh-config.XXXXXXXXXXX)
        trap 'rm "$tmp"' exit
        {
            printf "%s\n" "Host *" "  User somebody"
            # silence errors, if the files doesn't exists
            cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config ~/.ssh/config 2>/dev/null ||true
        } > "$tmp"
        ssh -F "$tmp" "$@"
    )
}
```

Comment: To the downvoter: Why was this answer downvoted?